# Accessing the data of a Parent model from a sub Model using the foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am quite new to API and Django, please pardon me, if this is a silly question, but I cannot seem to get my head around it.

I have 2 models (ProductOrder and Product). The ProductOrder model has a foreign key from Product.

Here are the 2 models.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.name} Price => {self.price}'


class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_dis = models.FloatField()
    price = ** Need to get the price of the product using the product id **
    order_date = models.DateField()
    dis_price = price - order_dis
    

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.order_date} {self.dis_price}'
```

I intend to create an API and I wish to enter only the product_id and want to access the product price which would thereby aid in calc. some other fields. Is that possible?

Comment: I ll advice you to read about views in django. you ll get your answer on your own

Comment: I did go through it, couldn't really find anything. Could you please specify as to what I must look for?

Comment: What do you mean by aid in calc some other fields which fields are you talking about ? Can you explain ?

Comment: By some other fields I mean the dis_price which is equal to  price - dis. The price here is what I need to get from the product model, using the product_id (Foreign Key) in ProductOrder.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done using a calculation when querying the data.

You should ask yourself the question "Do I store this data on the database, or do I calculate it based on the data in the database?". In this case probably the second one is the correct.

This can be done using [QuerySet Annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/).

For the example, lets create some objects:

```py
product = Product.objects.create(name="bagel", price=1)
ProductOrder.objects.create(product=product, order_dis=2.5)
```

And now lets query for that order

```py
order = ProductOrder.objects.annotate(
    price=F("product__price"), 
    dis_price=F("product__price") - F("order_dis"),
).first()

print(order.price) # 1
print(order.dis_price) # 1.5
```

You can also implement it in Python to get the value for a single object:

```py
class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_dis = models.FloatField()
    order_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def get_dis_price(self) -> float:
        return self.product.price - self.order_dis

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.order_date} {self.dis_price}'
```

Then you will also be able to do

```py
order.get_dis_price() # 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks! So, I am using Modelviewset in views.py. If I understand correctly, I am supposed to write the query for order inside ProductOrder's ModelViewSet.

Comment: Correct, but also don't forget to add that field to the serializer too